# php custom post variables

Tags: php, post

is there a way to create custom post variables when a user presses submit, like this:

```
$_POST['var'] = 'hi';
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to set post values on the page with the form you should use hidden input tags.

i.e.

```
<input type="hidden" name="var" value="hi" />
```

It will be invisible and your receiving script will see that key/value passed along.

Answer (score 1):

Variables POSTed by the browser to your PHP script will  only correspond to the fields of the form that was used in the browser -- which means you have to put your *custom data* in that form.

If you don't want them displayed, you can use a `hidden` input field :

```
<input type="hidden" name="var" value="hi" />
```

But note that the data will still be sent by the browser -- which means you have to escape/filter/protect it, like any other value that comes from the user ; and it cannot be trusted : anyone can pretty easily modify the value of that form field, even if it's not visible.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that _anything_ from the browser should be considered tampered with.

Answer (score 0):

while $_POST variable is an array, you can also define var like this

```
$_POST['var'] = 'hi';
```

it is same like hidden field. :)